# Join class list of lists

Tags: python, list, class, methods

I've got this method:

```
    def add_duty(self, new_duty):
        self.duty.append(new_duty)
```

which is used to append some duties to employees:

```
manager_employee[2].add_duty(['Do sth', 'Shine'])
manager_employee[2].add_duty(['Swag'])
manager_employee[2].add_duty(['Lag'])
```

If printed it shows duties in this way:

```
[['Do sth', 'Shine'], ['Swag'], ['Lag']]
```

I want to merge this list of lists into a single one. I've been trying to do that with regular ways of merging list of lists but it seems that class list behave in different way(I'm a newbie). And when merged it displays:

```
['D', 'o', ' ', 's', 't', 'h', 'S', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'S', 'w', 'a', 'g', 'Lag']
```

I'm looking for this effect:

```
['Do sth', 'Shine', 'Swag', 'Lag']
```

I've looked over some forums but found no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix:** To merge `[['Do sth', 'Shine'], ['Swag'], ['Lag']]` you can use a simple list-comprehension

```
a = [['Do sth', 'Shine'], ['Swag'], ['Lag']]
a = [word for sublist in a for word in sublist]
```

---

**Best:** it would be to modify your `add_duty` to add only words to the `self.duty` list, not list

```
def add_duty(self, new_duty):
    if isinstance(new_duty, list):
        self.duty.extend(new_duty)
    else:
        self.duty.append(new_duty)

# call like
manager_employee[2].add_duty(['Do sth', 'Shine']) # with a list
manager_employee[2].add_duty('Swag')              # with a string
```

---

**Better:** Use `*args` syntax, that takes all given argument and store them in a list

```
def add_duty(self, *new_duty):  # new_duty contains all parameters, as a list
    self.duty.extend(new_duty)

# call with any amount of string
manager_employee[2].add_duty('Do sth', 'Shine', 'other')
manager_employee[2].add_duty('Do sth', 'Shine')
manager_employee[2].add_duty('Swag')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['Do sth', 'Shine'], ['Swag'], ['Lag']]

list_ = []

for i in l: list_ += i
print(list_)
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, that's the keyword dor list constructor

Comment: thanks @azro but in this namespace I am not using list functionlity

Comment: Yes, but let's not take the habit

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```py
from functools import reduce
l = [['Do sth', 'Shine'], ['Swag'], ['Lag']]
functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, l, [])
```

if you want something similar to functional programming